# Get column nullability using star macro in dbt

Tags: dbt

We are using **adapter.get_columns_in_relation** adapter object to fetch column information in our dbt type2 macro to compare source and target before executing alter statement on Target table, but this only fetches the column name and data type but does not include column nullability.  Does anyone have any suggestions on getting the column nullability details along with data type and column name?

Synopsis of my code looks like this

```
{% macro check_for_schema_changes(source_relation, target_relation) %}

  {% set schema_changed = False %}

  {%- set source_columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(source_relation) -%}
  {%- set target_columns = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(target_relation) -%}
  {%- set source_not_in_target = diff_columns(source_columns, target_columns) -%}
  {%- set target_not_in_source = diff_columns(target_columns, source_columns) -%}

  {% set new_target_types = diff_column_data_types(source_columns, target_columns) %}
```